# Ruby - the simplest way to read a text file inside a zip file

Tags: ruby, zip

What is the simplest way to read a text file inside a zip file in Ruby? Something similar to PHP's `file_get_contents("zip://archive.zip#article.txt")`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
require 'zip/zip'

Zip::ZipFile.new("archive.zip").read("article.txt")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it

```
require 'zip/zip'

Zip::ZipFile.open("my.zip", Zip::ZipFile::CREATE) {|zipfile|  puts zipfile.read("first.txt")}
```

Comment: LoadError: cannot load such file -- zip/zip

Comment: Install `gem install rubyzip2`

Comment: I installed `rubyzip` and it works. What's the difference between `rubyzip` and `rubyzip2`?

Comment: rubyzip2 is deprecated with BIG ERROR WARNINGS

Answer (score 1):

I think that should work:

```
require 'zipruby'

Zip::Archive.open('archive.zip') do |ar|
   ar.fopen('article.txt') do |f|
      content = f.read
      # do sth
   end
end
```